# Multiple stubs on a managed channel in grpc?

Tags: grpc

While reading through the Java documentation on the grpc website, I found the `newBlockingStub` and `newStub` generated methods being referenced.

My main interest in grpc is to use a single connection to handle multiple rpcs in parallel.

By making multiple calls to newBlockingStub/newStub, do I get all these stubs to use the same underlying connection, and thus still have my rpcs working in parallel?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please have a look here to learn how to improve your questions (formatting, proofreading, providing code etc.): https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 2):

The `Channel` manages sharing a single connection with multiple RPCs. As long as stubs use the same underlying `ManagedChannel`, they may share a single connection.

I say *may* share a connection, since the `ManagedChannel` can be configured with different policies, for things like load balancing. The point is that `ManagedChannel` handles those decisions and the stub isn't impacted.

Comment: So multiple `newBlockingStub`'s sharing one channel can be executed in parallel, right?

Comment: @TarasMykhalchuk, yes, but even a single `stub` can have multiple RPCs executed in parallel. Stubs in grpc-java are immutable and thus thread-safe; configuration changes return a new stub.