# shareChannel effect on Gatling gRPC

Tags: scala, grpc, gatling

I have a scenario to run 5000 bidiStream gRPC Users ramping up 2 Users / sec, this is my current settings

```
val grpcConf = grpc(managedChannelBuilder(s"${url}").usePlaintext())
                //.shareChannel
val settings_Result = grpc("name")
    .bidiStream[RequestName, ResponseName](RelayServerGrpc.METHOD, "NameStream")
//exec scenario
exec(
    httpconf.PaymentFinalizerProcess_Result
      .connect
      .header(metadataObject.Authorization)(s"Bearer ${metadataObject.TokenKey}")
      .endCheck(statusCode is Status.Code.OK)
  )
.exec(REST_API)
.exec(bidiStream_Complete)
```

Usually I will start to get `INTERNAL` errors at around 1800 Users (timestamp 900 sec), but when I turn on `.shareChannel` it would appear sooner at 900 Users (timestamp 450 sec). I have tested same scenario with both settings around 3-4 times to ensure the cause is from enabling `.shareChannel`

So I would want to ask the effect of `.shareChannel` to know more and improve this script, please help me on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `shareChannel` is used, all the virtual users share the same `ManagedChannel`.

One `ManagedChannel` (roughly speaking) uses one single TCP connection for all requests.

[Multiple stubs on a managed channel in grpc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49931590/multiple-stubs-on-a-managed-channel-in-grpc/49949118#49949118)
[TCP sessions with gRPC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52657113/tcp-sessions-with-grpc/52863526#52863526)

Sharing the TCP connection lowers resource consumption, so a higher throughput might be reached. This can be useful if the server's capability to handle a large amount of connections is not important in the load test.

---

In your case it seems that your server (or the load generator, or the network) cannot handle a large amount of in-flight requests in a single connection. That's OK, just don't use the `shareChannel` option. The load test is more realistic that way.

Comment: Merry Christmas George, thanks for clarifying my concerns